# QueryStringConverter is not working for unknown reason

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm writing a little library which is generating clients for WCF rest services. But I encountered a problem with nullable values: for unknown reason my custom `QueryStringConverter` is never being called althrough I see in debugger that WCF calls its `CanConvert` method. Here is code:

```
public class NullableQueryStringConverter : QueryStringConverter
{
    public static NullableQueryStringConverter Instance { get; } = new NullableQueryStringConverter();
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type)
    {
        if (base.CanConvert(type))
            return true;
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
        var canConvert = underlyingType != null && base.CanConvert(underlyingType);
        return canConvert;
    }

    public override object ConvertStringToValue(string parameter, Type parameterType)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(parameterType);

        // Handle nullable types
        if (underlyingType != null)
        {
            // Define a null value as being an empty or missing (null) string passed as the query parameter value
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter) ? null : base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, underlyingType);
        }

        return base.ConvertStringToValue(parameter, parameterType);
    }
}
```

and here is WCF service opening:

```
public void Start(Uri baseAddress)
{
    var serviceInterface = _serviceType.GetInterfaces()
                                       .First(i => i.GetCustomAttribute<ServiceContractAttribute>(true) != null);
    var attribute = _serviceType.GetCustomAttribute<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>(true);
    if (attribute?.InstanceContextMode == InstanceContextMode.Single)
    {
        var singleton = Activator.CreateInstance(_serviceType);
        ServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(singleton, baseAddress.Concat(_subAddress));
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceHost = new WebServiceHost(_serviceType, baseAddress.Concat(_subAddress));
    }
    ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
    var debugBehavior = ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.OfType<ServiceDebugBehavior>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (debugBehavior != null)
    {
        debugBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDebugBehavior { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
    }

    var webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
        ReaderQuotas =
                new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                {
                    MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxDepth = 32
                }
    };

    webHttpBinding.ContentTypeMapper = new NewtonsoftJsonContentTypeMapper();
    ServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceInterface, webHttpBinding, string.Empty);

    foreach (var endpoint in ServiceHost.Description.Endpoints)
    {
        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new NullableWebHttpBehavior
        {
            HelpEnabled = false,
            DefaultBodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            FaultExceptionEnabled = true
        });

        endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new NewtonsoftJsonBehavior());
    }

    ServiceHost.Open();
}
```

As you can see, I'm adding `NullableWebHttpBehavior` which is being called (at least `CanConvert` method) but after that WCF stills requiring parameters to be convertible by base class.

Here is link to project on github: [link](https://github.com/Pzixel/WcfRestClient). It's bizzare because I have very similar code in another project which is working fine.

Maybe I am missing something, I dunno. Files which contains all logic to be examined are: `NullableWebHttpBehavior.cs` and `ServiceManager.cs`. You can easily run a test (which is the only one here) and face with same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that this method causes exception to be rizen:

```
    protected override IDispatchMessageFormatter GetRequestDispatchFormatter(OperationDescription operationDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        if (operationDescription.IsGetOrDeleteOperation())
        {
            // no change for GET operations
            return base.GetRequestDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
        }

        if (operationDescription.Messages[0].Body.Parts.Count == 0)
        {
            // nothing in the body, still use the default
            return base.GetRequestDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, endpoint);
        }

        return new NewtonsoftJsonDispatchFormatter(operationDescription, true);
    }
```

For some reaon `base.GetRequestDispatchFormatter` is returning original `QueryStringConverter` which throws an error. So I just removed these `if`s and always using my custom `NewtonsoftJsonDispatchFormatter`, which has some overhead but works fine.